# Skipping the foreach IDisposable check with a Generic value type enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a confusing result with generics and constraints I'm trying to understand.  Leaving aside whether any of this is a good idea or not, this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IValueEnumerator<T, EnumeratorType> where EnumeratorType : struct
{
    T Current { get; }
    bool MoveNext();
    EnumeratorType GetEnumerator();
}
    
public struct MyEnumerable : IValueEnumerator<int, MyEnumerable>
{
    private int index;
    private int count;
    public MyEnumerable(int count)
    {
        this.index = -1;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public bool MoveNext() => ++index < count;
    public MyEnumerable GetEnumerator() => this;        
    public int Current => index;
}

public class Program
{   
    public static int Iterate<T>(T enumerable) where T : struct, IValueEnumerator<int, T>
    {
        int z = 0;
        foreach (int y in enumerable)
            z += y;
        return z;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var prevMem = System.GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();
        MyEnumerable z = new MyEnumerable();
        int result = Iterate(z);
        long diff = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread() - prevMem;
        Console.WriteLine($"Result was {result}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{diff} extra bytes allocated");
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

```
Result was 0
24 extra bytes allocated
```

Inside `Iterate` the foreach loop is generating code to box the enumerator and check if it implements `IDisposable`.  The boxing is causing the allocation.

If I change the type constraint for `Iterate` to be `where T : struct, IValueEnumerator<int, MyEnumerable>` the compiler seems to recognize that the iterator can't implement IDisposable and it skips the boxing and I get no allocations:

```
Result was 0
0 extra bytes allocated
```

I've tried on a variety of compilers and they all have the same behavior.

Is this by design?  I would think the original constraint clause would be enough for the compiler not to generate the `IDisposable` check.  Are there additional constraints I could add so that it would still be generic but have the compiler not implement the `IDisposable` check in the foreach, or at the least not do the boxing?

Comment: If you change the `IValueEnumerator<int, T>` to `IValueEnumerator<int, MyEnumerable>` is will become a `IValueEnumerator<int, IValueEnumerator<int, MyEnumerable>>` which doesn't look equal to each other.

Comment: Did you try both Release and Debug builds?

Comment: Ah ha, no I didn't.  In release it doesn't allocate if I do a warmup pass first.  So it's an optimization disabled in debug builds.  That helps explain things.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I've figured this out, both why it was happening and a fix.

First, this only happens in debug, not in release.  In release it seems the compiler is smart enough to avoid the extra `IDisposable` check.

Next, the `where T : struct, IValueEnumerator<int, MyEnumerable>` constraint tells the compiler that T will be a value type but doesn't tell it that T *won't* be `IDisposasble`.  In debug it seems the same generic function has to be able to run on any types allowed by the constraints and some of those types might implement `IDisposable` and some might not.  The path of least resistance for the compiler is to just box the value and check if it's an `IDisposable`.

Unfortunately there's nothing like `where T : not IDisposable` to assure the compiler that it won't have to dispose of the enumerator.  However we can go the other way and have the interface implement `IDisposable`.  Then the compiler *knows* that T is disposable and it can call `Dispose()` on it without boxing it first.

That is, it won't cause any boxing or extra allocations in debug if the interface looks like:

```
public interface IValueEnumerator<T, EnumeratorType> : IDisposable
    where EnumeratorType : struct, IDisposable
{
    T Current { get; }
    bool MoveNext();
    EnumeratorType GetEnumerator();
}
```

The implementing struct has to add an empty `Dispose()` method which the foreach will call after its iteration, which is less efficient than when the compiler knows the enumerator definitely doesn't implement `IDisposable` and can skip all that.  But it does avoid any boxing and there aren't any allocations made.

Comment: https://sharplab.io is very good for this kind of thing. The weird thing is that when you instantiate generics based on a struct, the Jitter has to generate ASM code for that specific type (no code reuse), so it should know already that `MyEnumerable` cannot be `IDisposable` (remember that structs cannot be derived, they are `sealed`) and using simple dynamic slicing it should be able to elide the entire `finally` code with the boxing. For some reason it doesn't do this.

Comment: Yep I was messing with sharplab during all this.  Told me what was happening but not why.  Didn't realize generics would expand for struct types, that's good to know.  Not sure why the compiler can't be smarter, then.  Perhaps it's just such an edge case no one noticed it during development.

Comment: It seems there is no specific optimization for the case when you do `var x = genericValue as ISomeInterface; if(x != null) ...` where it could elide the whole thing when `T` is a struct and does not implement that interface